# Why vuex state changes the original index of an array in vuedevtool?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex

I'm retrieving an array from vuex.state. Arrangement of retrieved array is different than original ones in vuex.state.

Retrieving the same array from vue component works fine. It seems that vuex.state try to sort the array!

````
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: [0.06, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.01, 0.09, 0.04, 0.2, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.03, 0.09, 0.03, 0.07],
      myArray2: this.$store.state.myArray,
    };
  }
</script>

```vuex.store
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    myArray: [0.06, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.01, 0.09, 0.04, 0.2, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.03, 0.09, 0.03, 0.07],
  },



expected result in vue devtools = 
0:0.06
1:0.1
2:0.05
3:0.1
4:0.01
5:0.09
6:0.04
7:0.2
8:0.04
9:0.08
10:0.08
11:0.03
12:0.09
13:0.03
14:0.07

actual result vue devtools = 
0:0.01
1:0.03
2:0.03
3:0.04
4:0.04
5:0.05
6:0.06
7:0.08
8:0.09
9:0.1
10:0.08
11:0.09
12:0.2
13:0.1
14:0.07
````

Comment: Vuex won't change the order. Either it's your code that's changing the order or some other library that you're using. The values aren't correctly sorted, which may help to narrow down the culprit.

Comment: @skirtle Your right. Somewhere in calculations I was ranking the array and because arrays are reference type, the new arrangement is reflected on the original array. Thank you